# $facebook->api() call returns CurlException: 7?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

After authorizing my app, I'm redirecting the user to my php-script:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXX',
    'secret' => 'XXX',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$fbUser = $facebook->api('/me');
```

The getUser()-Function properly returns my Facebook-UserID, but as soon as I am trying to fetch further information with $facebook->api('/me'), the following error-message is returned:

> Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in /XXX/base_facebook.php on line 886

Strange thing is, that the exact same code has been working for months on the very same server?!

Comment: This is not related to code but current API problems (see [Platform Live Status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status) or server networking issue (like not updated DNS)

Comment: According to Facebook, the API problems have been fixed. I still get the same error message, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem!

The hoster has blocked the ports 80 and 443. After reactivating them, everything worked fine.